# Speed html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

We have a mobile web application. It is an application where people fill out forms and towards the end, be  able to sign the form electronically 
we are planning to use html5 canvas based sketch pads.

Apart from the drawing we need additional parameters like acceleration or velocity would like to know how to find out the velocity/speed of movement.

Is this something we can calculate by finding the distance divided by time? i.e. distance start (x,y) to end (x,y) divided by time taken?

Comment: Speed is calculated by distance divided by time.  Mouse events include `event.timeStamp` which lets you calculate times between events. Mouse events also include `[event.clientX,event.clientY]` positions which let you calculate distance traveled by the mouse between events. You're done!

Comment: Thanks Mark! for the details